# Electromagnetic Waves in Nature

Tags: electromagnetism

How is the electric field portion of an EM wave used?  The magnetic field part is used to induce a signal in conductors, and are used in radios.  I have researched but I can't seem to find there being any devices that use the electric field portion of an EM wave.

Comment: electric dipole antenna

Comment: It's the electric part of the wave that is used in most detectors (including the most famous of all, your eye), because the magnetic force is weaker than the electric by a factor of $v/c$, which is typically small.

Comment: @Javier Thanks, now I got my  _**eye**_ on the game. :)